# Use Kalman filter to predict

Tags: probability-or-statistics, filtering, signal-processing

Here is a set of altitude data I collected with an *Arduino* sensor *BMP-180* on a board *CanSat*

```
data = {13.15, 13.4, 13.15, 13.31, 13.4, 13.31, 13.15,.....}
```

how can I use *Kalman Filter* in *Mathematica* to do the prediction on that set of data?

Comment: Does your question relate to the software Mathematica or to the science of mathematics.  If the latter, I suggest that you move your question to [math.se].

Comment: ... or maybe even [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: ... and next to data the good old question remains: "What is your *model*?" Have a look at the documentation for [KalmanFilter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KalmanFilter.html?q=KalmanFilter).

Comment: @gwr ...which is probably much harder to answer than the original question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this perhaps.

```
tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[data];
ListLinePlot[{tsm["TemporalData"],
  TimeSeriesForecast[Normal[tsm], data, {6}, Method -> "Kalman"]}]
```

Comment: Thanks! May I also know how I can get the position of a certain value through the prediction?

Comment: For example: `Select[TimeSeriesForecast[Normal[tsm], data, {30}, 
   Method -> "Kalman"]["Path"], Last[#] <= 13 &]`